# Removal of an arbitrary point of the boundary of a closed and connected $A\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ so the new set remains connected

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

> Prove the following statement or find a counterexample:
>
> Let $A\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ be a closed and connected set. Then,$\exists c\in\partial A$ s. t. $A\setminus\{c\}$ is still connected.

I think I found some counterexamples:

$x$ or $y$ axis or any other line in $\Bbb R^2,$ as well as graphs of unbounded continuous functions defined on an open interval $I\subseteq\Bbb R$ or graphs of continuous functions defined on the whole $\Bbb R.$

**Question** :

> Is the unboundedness necessary for the statement **not** to hold?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the following answer in Whyburn's book *Analytic topology* in Chapter 3, Theorem 6.1 :

> Every continuum has at least two non-cut points.

Where, (Chapter 1, 10.)

> A compact connected set will be called a *continuum*

and, (Chapter 3, 1.)

> If $M$ is a connected set and $p$ is a point of $M$ such that the set $M \setminus p$ is not connected, then $p$ will be called a *cut point* of $M$.

Now, if we take $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ closed, connected and bounded, $A$ is compact by the [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem). So it is a *continuum* and it has two non-cut points which means that there exists (at least two) points $c$ such that $A \setminus c$ is connected. **This solves the case $\mathring{A} = \emptyset$** which intuitively corresponds to curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

For the general case, I think that the theorem still holds because $\mathring{A} \neq \emptyset$ looks like a strong condition to me but I haven't been through yet.

Comment: Take a closed « ring » in $\mathbb{R^2}$, ie just a closed ball amputed from an inside closed ball for instance $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2, \ 1 \leqslant ||x|| \leqslant 2 \}$. It is a closed blounded set thus compact, it is obviously path-connected so connected and $A \setminus \mathring{A} = \partial A = S(0,1) \cup S(0,2)$ is the union of the 2 circles of radius 1 and 2 which is not connected !

Comment: But this just shows $\operatorname{Int}(A)$ doesn't correspond to curves in $\Bbb R^2,$ right (I mean, your comment, not the accepted answer $\color{blue}{(:}$    ) ?

Comment: A small remark: The Theorem 6.1 you cite also needs the assumption that the space contains more than one point to begin with. Of course a singleton is connected and compact but does not contain two non-cut points. But I also do not see how your comment helps with what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Oops someone had asked for an example of compact connected set with non-connected boundary and then deleted its question !!